# scrollbar in a gridview

Tags: gridview

I use `overflow:scroll;` to create a scrollbar to a gridview. However this creates the scrollbar on the right side. IS it possible to create the scroll bar on the left side of the gridview?

Answer (score 1):

Try [this](http://forums.asp.net/post/2365564.aspx) from ASP.NET forum, there is direction attribute to set.

Answer (score 1):

[Amazing Link For Total GridView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms228113%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)